# Flutter : Value not chaning visually Textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a little problem, I made a class called TextFieldFactory which I use in my page

when I try to change a value for example on a date type field, and I select a date, the value is saved from what I have seen but visually it is not put in the field. I have this on all my forms that use this. Note that the date, datetime, tinyint(1) field does not work but if I do for a varchar or an enum the visual value changes if someone can help me

https://filebin.net/7tgelx4fyribw1mz

Comment: Jonathan, please share code form not attachment to make it easy to respond

Comment: Use `key: ValueKey(currentValue)` for text fields. Read more about `Key`s.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.